# How to attach things to an Event object before it gets bubbled up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to insert a property like foo = 1 to an event object in the button listener callback so that the body listener callback gets it as well:

```
$(function() {

    $("button").click(function(e) {
        alert("first");    
        // attach foo to e
    });

    $("body").click(function(e) {
        alert("second");
        // e has foo
    });

});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exSKF/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery seems to build a new event wrapper object for every stage of the event flow. You can however access the actual event object through the [`originalEvent` property](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

So use

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.foo = 1;
});
$("body").click(function(e) {
    alert(e.originalEvent.foo);
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/exSKF/2/))